# I am not able to send a string correctly from javascript to server

Tags: javascript, php, post, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send a string to my server using the following script:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'execute.php', true);
var data = 'name=John';
xhr.send(data);
```

However, on the server side, when **execute.php** is executed,

```
isset($_POST['name'])
```

it returns `false`. This is the only request to the server.

Why isn't `$_POST['name']` set and how to fix it?

Comment: Is `HMLHttpRequest` a typo here, or is that how you have it? Should it not be `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: Yeah sorry I had it correctly in the original code.

Comment: I think you are missing a request header... try:
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

(Before you send the data)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a request header before sending the data:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'execute.php', true);
var data = 'name=John';
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Good catch on the content-type

Comment: It has happened to me way too many times, it may trigger a false value on the $_POST variables.

Comment: It worked, thanks! But is it possible it doesn't for long strings such as base64 images? Is it restricted somehow?

Comment: @EricValls Worry not, you can limit the php_value post_max_size in your php.ini file. I use the value 512M in one of my servers, and works great.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to encode your data when POSTing (MIME types).  PHP's $_POST only automatically decodes www-form-urlencoded

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'execute.php', true);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
var data = 'name=John';   

xhr.send(data);
```

If you send JSON encoded data, you must read the entire post body and json decode it yourself.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'execute.php', true);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
var data = JSON.stringify({'name':'John'});

xhr.send(data);
```

in PHP...

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$myPost = json_decode($entityBody);
$myPost['name'] == 'John';
```

Use your browser's network inspector (f12) to see what is going on.